# Php index of element in the array, update element

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

for some reason `$post` is always < 0. The indoxOf function works great. I use it on ohter codes and it works great

for some reason even after I add the element like this `array_push($groups, $tempDon);` on the next loop i continues to return -1

```
$donations = $this->getInstitutionDonations($post->ID);

            $groups=array();

            foreach( $donations as $don ) : setup_postdata($don); 

                $pos = $this->indexOf($don, $groups);

                print_r($pos);

                if($pos < 0)
                {
                    $tempDom = $don;

                    $tempDon->count = 1;

                    array_push($groups, $tempDon);
                }
                else
                {
                    $tempDom = $groups[$pos];

                    $tempDon->count++;

                    array_splice($tempDon);

                    array_push($groups, $tempDon);

                    echo '<br><br><br>ahhhhhhhhhh<br><br>';
                }
            endforeach;

     protected function indexOf($needle, $haystack) {            // conversion of JavaScripts most awesome
        for ($i=0;$i<count($haystack);$i++) {         // indexOf function.  Searches an array for
                if ($haystack[$i] == $needle) {       // a value and returns the index of the *first*
                        return $i;                    // occurance
                }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Well, maybe because you never change the value of `$pos`?

Comment: Please do not mix standard and alternative syntax for if / foreach etc. The readbility of your code will increase. Next to that, the definition of `indexOf` is unknown (you need to add the code), and what is `$don`?

Comment: -1??  well i shoud change `$pos = $this->indexOf($don, $groups);` so the next time the loop acour the `groups` will have one element and I am forcing the element to be the same... Still didn't get why -1 this is not fair

Comment: `$don` is the current element of the array `$donations` spcified on the foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue of poor proofreading to me (note **$tempDom** vs **$tempDon**):

```
                $tempDom = $don;

                $tempDon->count = 1;

                array_push($groups, $tempDon);
```

Your `else` block has similar issues.

I also completely agree with @hakre's comment regarding syntax inconsistencies.

**EDIT**

I'd also like to recommend that you make use of PHP's built-in [array_search](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function in the body of your `indexOf` method rather than rolling your own.

Comment: I agree too.. but I'm not a php programmer, just trying to fix some problems on the code... :( by the way, I fixed the proofreading  issues, but nothing changed. still not getting into else

Comment: Just because you're not getting into the `else` block doesn't mean there's an error. It looks like you'll only hit the `else` block if `$don` already exists in the `$groups` array, which would indicate a duplicate of some kind. If you have no duplicates in `$donations` you will not reach the `else` block.

Comment: you're right. I had no duplicated elements, even tough I though I had. thkx a lot. By the I'm using `array_sarch()` too. tkx!